# $2$ different $3\times 3$ matrices, $1$ of its eigenvalue is exactly the same, is the eigenvector same?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let's say we have $2$ different $3\times 3$ matrices, $1$ of its eigenvalue is exactly the same, does the eigenvector correspond to that same eigenvalue going to be the same between the $2$ different matrices?

Comment: Have you tried to find examples? How about $\text{Diag}(1,2,3)$ and $\text{Diag}(0,1,5)$$

Answer (score 1):

No.

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
$

and

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$

both have an eigenvalue of $1$ but have different eigenvectors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there a way to generalise your answer to a nxn matrices?